# Media Dialog CSS broken in WP v.5.3.2

Tags: plugins, media-library, bug

My plugin displays the media picker dialog on the users front end. If a user has WordPress 5.2.2 installed then the media picker dialog looks nice/normal (see the first image). If they have WordPress 5.3.2 installed then the dialog seems to be affected by the front-end (theme?) styling.

Does anyone know how I can overcome this? Is this a known problem that WordPress knows about and is fixing?

**Edit** Actually, it seems to be looking normal on my v5.2.2 website due to other plugins being installed. If I deactivate them then I get the same styling issue.

I enqueue the media stuff in the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' action. Is that the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I enqueue the media stuff" - do you mean the CSS? Yes, that's right. Or do you mean a hidden modal dialog or something? That might also be OK too - you'd have to check how the HTML ended up.

Comment: Since you're already working with the developer tools, can you work out what's different between the working and not working versions? Compare the CSS that you're downloading, and compare HTML tree in the inspector tag, or save the HTML pages to disk and diff them.

Comment: Is this a known bug? Your best bet might be to look at the WordPress Trac to see if anyone's reported, or try a nightly build. But if you're going to report it yourself then you'll have to debug it first to work out what's actually gone wrong.